# What would happen if I don't close the database in Android?

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

This title may sound a little bit crazy, but this is what is making me confused. My app heavily uses local database operations. As suggested in the Android docs and some blogs, I extended the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class and defined all my DB operations there. As some of my DB operations execute in threads, opening and closing of the db causes some `IllegalStateExceptions`. So, I made my DB helper as `Singleton` and it resolved those issues, also getting rid of the `open` and `close` operations for every DB action. Now everything seems to be working fine even though I never close the DB.

- My confusion is that is it necessary to close DB?
- If so, what is the right place to do so, is it in `onDestroy` of the main activity or somewhere else?
- If I don't close DB, what are the side effects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch `IllegalStateException` if you'll try to open again the same database.

If you create instance of `DBHelper` in `onCreate` method of main activity - it would be write to close db in `onDestroy`. So, you can be sure, that next time in `onCreate` your database is not opened already.

If you have reference to `DBHelper` in service, than it should be opened and closed in service, and not in activity.

You can also use `Application` class for opening db, but than it will opened every time when you app starts (for example when you receive `BroadcastReceiver`)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get exceptions is that *you are trying to write/read from the same database via different threads*.

I believe the best place to close your database would be inside the `onDestroy()` of your **mainActivity**.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem.I opened database ,perform some operation and i forget to close.Actually i saw some exceptions i logcat that is "Leak found" db is opened and never closed.